# Modelling members who will switch to a new to product when it's launched

Tags: r, forecasting, marketing

I have been asked to build a model that will help estimate how many insurance plan members will move from an existing product to the new product over time.

The details of the project have yet to be defined but I am interested in doing some research on existing approaches prior to the project kicking off.

In my example we have 10000 members who take drugs in a therapeutic class i.e. Hemophilia. There are 4 existing products that we currently cover and there will be a new market entrant in the coming months. 6000 members take Drug A, 3000 take Drug B, 800 take Drug C and 200 take Drug D. The data I have access consists of historical claims for all of these products (# claims, dosage, strength, days supply of drugs, claim cost, member cost share, # days between infusions etc.) for each member going back 3 years. I have access to demographic data as well as health information i.e. medical diagnosis codes for all medical visits dating back 3 years.

The first thing that sprung to mind was Markov models i.e. each product could be a state with the transition matrix comprised of the probabilities of members moving between products or staying on a particular product?

Based on the limited details I have provided can anyone make a suggestion as to which type of model would seem appropriate for this kind of problem?

Comment: To me it is unclear, what data you have to build a model on and what knowledge on top of that data should go into model building.

Comment: @Bernhard I have hopefully provided more context that would help to understand my business problem

Comment: Markov chain or any other curve fitting is wrong approach, what you need is to conduct a market research approach called demand study where you interview physicians to understand prescribing dynamics . This is highly specialized area, I think it’s better to consult domain experts. You need to understand fundamentals/Properties of why patients/Physicians want to switch before any modeling exercise. Also things like order of entry, class of drug, clinical trial/superiority/parity of the index drug matters, statistical models don’t help here.

Comment: The word you need is **marketing**. That is a field all on its own. Although some statistics is involved, it stands apart from routine statistical analysis.